# Find documents with array of string ID's in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, objectid

I have an string array of id's that i'd like to use with the find function.

```
db.companies.find( { _id : { $in : arr} });
```

`arr` looks something like this,

```
[ '563a2c60b511b7ff2c61e938', '563a2c60b511b7ff2c61e8b7' ];
```

I see from the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) that `ObjectID()` doesn't accept arrays. How can I search for a list of documents with this array? Will I have to recreate the array so that all elements are ObjectID's?

Comment: What is the output when you run that query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use the `map` function to get the list of `ObjectId`'s from the list of string ids:

```
arr.map(function (id) {
  return ObjectId(id);
})
```

Plugged into your query:

```
db.companies.find({_id: { $in: arr.map(function (id) {return ObjectId(id);})}})
```